# Authorization on Azure Logic Apps with Azure AD BC2 - Supplied token returns SecurityTokenInvalidSignature

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I am using Azure AD BC2 and I'd like to apply authorization on my Logic App.

When I execute the supplied URL **([https://prod-19.northcentralus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/{someId}/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01](https://prod-19.northcentralus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/%7BsomeId%7D/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01))** via Postman (I dropped all the SAS Querystring parameters already), I receive this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "SecurityTokenInvalidSignature",
        "message": "The provided authentication token is not valid, token signature is not properly formatted."
    }
}
```

But the token is really Ok, I can ensure. I tested in 2 diff ways:

1- Pasted the JWT token at https://jwt.io/ and It was capable to decode all the claims plus all headers such as nonce, typ, etc...

2- I used this very same token to retrieve users via https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

I also mapped the policy in this way:

- Issued --> JTW iss claim
- Audience --> JTW aud claim
- appid ---> JWT appid claim (this is a custom property)

I can't understand why I am receiving this error. Any clue ?